# How much "Earned uptime credit" do I get when staking Loki on a Service Node?

Tags: monero-forks, loki, service-node

How much earned up time credit do I get when I stake Loki on my service node? What is the maximum amount of credit can I get? And how does one calculate the how much you earn in a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should find your answer here https://lokidocs.com/ServiceNodes/DeregistrationRules/#decommission-and-credits